# Преобразование типов void* в char ** (язык Си)

Tags: c, преобразование-типов

Пишем с сокомандником проект, сокомандник записывает различные аргументы в переменную void* ptr как двумерный массив, а я потом получаю данный void* ptr и должен обработать его как char**.

Понимаю, как работает кастинг на базовом уровне (преобразование типов)

```
    void* ptr;
    char** ptrchar;
    ptrchar = (char**)ptr;
```

Но мне кажется, что такое преобразование типов не будет работать, т.к. передается указатель на одномерный массив void, а мне нужно работать с двумерным массивом? Есть ли ошибка в нашей логике?

И прошу описать, как надо сделать кастинг из таких разных типов, если это действительно работает.

Comment: `записывает различные аргументы в переменную void* ptr как двумерный массив`. Приведите пример кода. По такому описанию не очень понятно, что за указатель хранится в переменной типа `void*`.

Comment: Если это традиционный двумерный массив (т.е. все элементы расположены в памяти последовательно), то предчувствие вас не обмануло, работать не будет. Для обработки двумерного массива, представленого как одномерный, нужно знать размер строки (количество столбцов). Тогда для обращения к элементу `a[i][j]` (i -- номер строки) можно писать **`a[i * n_cols + j]`**

Comment: Преобразование указателя `void * ` -> `char * *` правильное только если он указывает на объект типа `char *`. Вот и весь ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в логике есть. Тип `char**` это не указатель на двухмерный массив. Это указатель на указатель на `char`. Его же можно трактовать как указатель на одномерный массив указателей на одномерные массивы `char` (либо одиночные `char`). А если нужен указатель именно на двухмерный массив, то он определяется так:

```
char (*ptrchar)[NUM_COLUMNS];
```

И динамически создаётся так (С++):

```
ptrchar = new char[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLUMNS];
```

Или так (в C):

```
ptrchar = (char(*)[NUM_COLUMNS])malloc(sizeof(char)*NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLUMNS);
```

Как видите, количество столбцов должно быть явно указано в типе и оно не может быть переменной. Это связано с тем, что двухмерный массив - это массив одномерных массивов, и чтобы вычислить позицию заданного элемента по индексам `i` и `j` компилятору необходимо знать ширину строки (число столбцов).

Что касается приведения указателя к `void*` и хранения его в этом типе, то ключевой вопрос: зачем? Тут тоже отчётливо пахнет ошибочной логикой, хотя вы не привели конкретный  код. С подобными преобразованиями типов указателей надо обращаться крайне осторожно, т.к. они легко могут приводить к неопределённому поведению.

Comment: Тот факт, что `NUM_COLUMNS` в подобных выражениях д.б. константой, делает все подобные "типы" указателей практически бессмысленными. На практике (для массивов любой размерности) мы всегда используем приведение к одиночному указателю на тип элемента массива

Comment: @avp это особенность работы с "классическими" матрицами в C/C++. На практике же гораздо эффективнее использовать одномерные массивы и обращаться к элементам через выражение `i*width+j`.

Comment: Именно это я и написал ТС в своем комментарии под его вопросом

Comment: @avp ну вопрос был, в частности, про двухмерный массив, про него я и ответил.